# PROJ_LIB error in Spyder with importing basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

I am very new to python, and I am trying to import `basemap` into Spyder 3.6. I used `conda install basemap` in Anadonda Prompt and in Spyder `import basemap`, but I get an error

```
  File "<ipython-input-1-d9467465a3b6>", line 1, in <module>
    from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

  File "D:\Anaconda_Python\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\basemap\__init__.py", line 155, in <module>
    pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_LIB']

  File "D:\Anaconda_Python\lib\os.py", line 678, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None

KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB'
```

I have looked in similar questions, but it did not work for me:

- [How can I avoid PROJ_LIB error in importing basemap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201946/how-can-i-avoid-proj-lib-error-in-importing-basemap)
  But error just changed to `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\Anaconda_Python\\share\\proj\\epsg'`
- https://github.com/conda-forge/basemap-feedstock/issues/30

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a common problem. The issue lies in Basemap not properly locating where Proj4's "epsg" file is. 
This can be easily fixed by first finding where the file 'epsg' is located then use some code to add the path itself.

It should be somewhere like this (this is where mine is located, varies depending on the environment name and location where you downloaded Anaconda)

C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\envs\env\Library\share

Looking at your error message I believe yours should be located somewhere in "D:\Anaconda_Python\share"

Then insert the following code before importing Basemap and it should work.

```
import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = r'C:\Users\XXX\Anaconda3\envs\env\Library\share (location of epsg)'
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Comment: Worked for me! Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me using os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = r'/opt/anaconda3/share/proj'

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy  epsg file to the directory where it searches for it, in your case `D:\\Anaconda_Python\\share\\proj\\`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error (Windows 10, Anaconda). So I tried to find "epsg" file which appeared at 'C:\Users\Yury\anaconda3\Library\share' and by adding these lines I got it finally working

```
import os
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = 'C:\\Users\\Yury\\anaconda3\\Library\\share'
```

or same can be done

```
import os
import conda
conda_file_dir = conda.__file__
conda_dir = conda_file_dir.split('lib')[0]
proj_lib = os.path.join(os.path.join(conda_dir, 'Library'), 'share')
os.environ["PROJ_LIB"] = proj_lib
```

Thank you for this piece of code